# Can I use a LINQ if statement with a boolean... all inside a select new? C#

Tags: c#, linq

First time working with Linq so I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about what I want to do...any advice is appreciated.

I want to use the boolean m.IsDog to add the word Dog to the end of the m.Behavior string. If it is indeed a dog, then "-Dog" gets added, if not then I just want the m.Behavior.

I have this in my code, and it's been working like I wanted to in the APIs response.

```
select new ReportCard
{
Id = m.Id,
Name = $"{m.FirstName} {m.LastName}",
Age = m.Age,
Attitude = m.IsDog ? m.Behavior + "-Dog" : m.Behavior
```

I'm stuck though, because I also want to write something similar to the following:

*If m.Behavior = "G" then "Good" else "Bad"*

So that my API responses can be "Good-Dog" , "Bad-Dog", "Bad", "Good" without changing the database values.

Is it even possible to do something like that in the same line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps changing this line from:

```
Attitude = m.IsDog ? m.Behavior + "-Dog" : m.Behavior
```

to:

```
Attitude = (m.Behavior.StartsWith("G") ? "Good" : "Bad") + (m.IsDog ? "-Dog" : "")
```

would help?

Keep in mind, this would only match `Behavior`s that match an Upper Case "G".

Comment: That did the trick!! Didn't realize StartsWith was an option. Thank you so much for your quick response. I'll be doing a lot more reading on Linq before I keep going I guess.

Comment: `StartsWith` is actually an option on any string, it doesn't have anything to do with Linq. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0

Comment: You could also always access values from a `string` as if it were an array. `m.Behavior[0] == 'G' ? "Good" : "Bad"` should also work.